# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wc_get_page_id()

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Im getting this error on my WooCommerce Cart Page when it is empty, how would I get rid of this error message?

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function wc_get_page_id(), 0 passed in
>   /home/s3morder/public_html/wp-content/themes/Intranet
>   Theme/woocommerce/cart/cart-empty.php on line 30 and exactly 1
>   expected in
>   /home/s3morder/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-page-functions.php:45 Stack trace: #0 /home/s3morder/public_html/wp-content/themes/Intranet
>   Theme/woocommerce/cart/cart-empty.php(30): wc_get_page_id() #1
>   /home/s3morder/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(211):
>   include('/home/s3morder/...') #2
>   /home/s3morder/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-cart.php(85):
>   wc_get_template('cart/cart-empty...') #3
>   /home/s3morder/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php(76):
>   WC_Shortcode_Cart::output(Array) #4
>   /home/s3morder/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php(89):
>   WC_Shortcodes::shortcode_wrapper(Array) #5
>   /home/s3morder/public_html/wp- in
>   /home/s3morder/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-page-functions.php
>   on line 45

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you modified the cart code? the error says only that the function wc_get_page_id() was with 0 arguments called but 1 argument is required

Comment: if not please show us the code from /Intranet Theme/woocommerce/cart/cart-empty.php on line 30 (show us more than line 30)

Comment: So the template file `cart/cart-empty.php` located in your **"Intranet Theme"** theme folder **is the guilty** and you should contact the theme authors support threads, as we don't handle support in StackOverFlow

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec for the help, I figured out what it was and got it working like normal.

Comment: Thank you @Tobias as well for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was an extra function in the empty-cart.php that I hadn't gotten rid of, once I narrowed down where the error's started, I figured out what I needed to get rid of, the cart-empty.php file is as is below.

```
<?php

   if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
      exit; // Exit if accessed directly
   }
?>
<div class="text-center">
   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty' );?>
</div>
```

And the response given is `Your cart is currently empty.` Which is perfect!
I hope this helps someone!